# preg_match match all starting words

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to get all matched patterns from a list of words;

```
$pattern = '/^(ab|abc|abcd|asdf)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, 'abcdefgh', $matches);
```

I want to get '**ab, abc and abcd**'

But this return only '**ab**'. It works if I loop through patterns after exploding them.

Is there any way to solve it though single match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions consume characters as they are matching through the string, so they can't natively find overlapping matches.

You can use extended features like lookahead assertions together with capturings groups, but that requires an ugly construction:

```
preg_match_all(
    '/^
    (?:(?=(ab)))?
    (?:(?=(abc)))?
    (?:(?=(abcd)))?
    (?:(?=(asdf)))?
    /x', 
    $subject, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);
for ($matchi = 0; $matchi < count($result); $matchi++) {
    for ($backrefi = 0; $backrefi < count($result[$matchi]); $backrefi++) {
        # Matched text = $result[$matchi][$backrefi];
    } 
}
```